# How to find the minimum distance .. when two points belongs to same distance

Tags: python, pandas, matching, pairwise

I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
A  B  
1 0.1 
1 0.2
1 0.3
2 0.2
2 0.5
2 0.3
3 0.8
3 0.6
3 0.1
```

How can I find the minimum value belonging to each point 1,2,3 and there should be no conflict which means point 1 and 2 should not belong to same point 0.3..

Comment: Are you looking for a solution with `pandas`? If so, could you add the tag?

Comment: yes.. thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do two things:
- find the minimum `B` per distinct `A`, and
- make sure that they don't collide. You didn't specify what to do in case of collision, so I assume you just want to know if there is one.

The first can be achieved with Rarblack's answer (though you should use `min` and not `max` in your case).
For the second, you can use the `.nunique()` method - see how many unique `B` values are there (should be same as number of unique `A` valuse)

```
#setup dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    'B': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.6,0.1]
})

# find minimum
x = df.groupby('A')['B'].min()

# assert that there are no collisions:
if not (x.nunique() == len(x)):
    print ("Conflicting values")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. your understanding is correct.. In case of collision, i want to print the closest number belong to A value..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `max` function.

```
df.groupby('A').B.max()
```